# How to get position of item clicked on listview?

Tags: android, listview

my activity code to get position of item on ListActivity to update status checked to database

```
public class ViewList extends ListActivity {
private ListViewAdapter lAdapter;   
DBAdapter db;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();      
    Cursor cursor = db.fetchAllDeliveryItem();
    lAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),cursor);     
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cursor.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setListAdapter(lAdapter);

}
private class ListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter{


@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}




@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView tvListText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);
    CheckBox cbListCheck = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);

    tvListText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("itemname")));
    **cbListCheck.setChecked((cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("delivered"))==0? false:true));
    cbListCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             db.updateItem(position);**


        }
    });

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return li.inflate(R.layout.receiverow, parent, false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call setOnItemClickListener on your ListView. Its callback function includes the position of the view that is clicked as a argument. Here is an example:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id){

        // DO STUFF HERE

    }
});
```

**Edit**: Sorry I thought you were using a ListView not a ListActivity. Its even easier for a ListActivity as you simply implement the following method in your ListActivity:

```
onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

Comment: but my layout doesn't a listview

Comment: then simply implement: onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) in your ListActivity.  Its very clear in the docs:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: I create a int position; and assign this.position = position on onListItemClick method but it return 0 every item i clicked :(

Comment: NO NO NO! You don't need to create the position variable. When you click on the item in the list, the list object calls that onItemClicked method and provides that method with the position.  If this isn't making sense I suggest you buy a book about beginning android development. It will explain this it a lot more detail then I can here.

Comment: thank you! But i wanna call this method when clicked item db.updateItem(position); i need to create avaiable :-??

Answer (score 0):

In the case of ListActivity, you can override the method [onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) in the [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend ListActivity you can override the onListItemClick method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should implement

onListItemClick

and override the method :

```
 @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);  

Log.i("the Item clicked is at position : ",  position);

    }
```