# Get clicked ListView item number

Tags: android

How do I get the number of a listview item, that is clicked, so I then can send that number through an Intent?

**Example**

I click the list item number 2 and that returns 1 (As they start from 0).

Comment: you already knows the answer.

Comment: @mitesh Read the question before you make those statements. He wouldn't post it here if he knew the answer.

Comment: you should google it before asking such a silly questions. Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448585/how-to-get-position-of-item-clicked-on-listview

Comment: This is an entirely different statement. True or not. And even if dasmikko could find the answer after better research, the question is still far from silly.

Comment: @dasmikko Did you even want to send the Intent immediately upon the click? If I had known this, I'd have given a different answer. -- Anyway, have you enabled your ListView for single choice? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The onItemClick is called when you click on a listitem, the 3rd argument is the index of item clicked.

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
    {
       Log.i.("app","I clicked item number " + position);
       //int position is your index , 0,1,2 etc.
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Next.class);
       myIntent.putExtra("itemNumber",position);
       startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason I just get null when I try to send "position" through a Intent.

Comment: Have you tried to log it when you click? position argument in the onItemClick shouldn't contain null. Sending position through intent not working seems to be an entirely different problem.

Comment: How do I exactly log the click?

Comment: Added log code to the answer

Answer (score 0):

[`ListView.getCheckedItemPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPosition%28%29) is your friend.