# ListView in fragment android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

How to get the List Item position?
I was just trying to **learn fragment**. I saw the example of `ListFragment` on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com),  but it's hard for me to understand.

So I used a `ListView` in `Fragment` but when I click the items I can't get its position. How can I obtain that?

```
public class Fragment_listview extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    String[] days={"Sun","Mon","Tue"};
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        listView= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,days);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set listener to your `ListView`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this job, usually you need to call `setOnItemClickListener` on your `ListView`. Its callback function includes the position of the view that is clicked as a argument. Here is an example:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id){

        // DO STUFF HERE

    }
});
```

As your `Activity` already implements `AdapterView`, you simply have to set the `OnItemClickListener` of your `listView` to the `Activity` itself, as below

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

disclaimer: part of this answer it take from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7448619/3178454)