# ListView changing views during scrolling after adjusting them programmatically

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

*I spent all last evening to find any solution about my problem but I didn't, so it's not duplicate.*

I have a listView and simple ArrayAdapter. I want each time when I click on item its textView field becomes bold, and previous if it exists becomes normal. It's very simple problem, but I have caught a lot of troubles.

My device can show 13 items at once. So, if I don't scroll everything works. But if I try to scroll, I find some next items become also bold and the click event works unproperly. In debug I see listView has only first 13 elements. I understand that adapter loads others asyncronically but how to solve my problem in these conditions?

Here is my code:

```
ListView listLibrary;
int posPrev;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_info);

    listLibrary = findViewById(R.id.listSongs);
    listLibrary.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    fillList();
    posPrev = -1;
}

private void fillList() {
    String[] arrList = {"New York", "San Francisco", "Los Angeles", "Dallas", "Houston", "Tucson", "Phoenix", "Denver", "Las Vegas", "Kansas City", "Chicago", "Detroit", "Atlanta", "Miami", "Philadelphia", "Baltimore", "Washington", "Boston", "Pittsburg", "Columbus", "Cincinnati", "Indianapolis", "St. Louis", "Seattle", "Portland", "San Jose", "San Diego", "San Antonio"};
    ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : arrList)
        cities.add(s);

    if (listLibrary != null) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cities);
        listLibrary.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    if (posPrev != -1) {
        ((TextView)listLibrary.getChildAt(posPrev)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }

    ((TextView)listLibrary.getChildAt(i)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    posPrev = i;
}
```

**EDIT**
So as you had suggested I added custom adapter. If tvCaption.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL) is removed I get randomly bold items next of list. Actually I understand the problem I don't know how to solve it.

```
 ArrayList<String> cities;
Context context;
int resource;
TextView tvCaption;
int posClicked;

public CustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    cities = (ArrayList) objects;

    posClicked = -1;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null);
    }

    tvCaption = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCaption);
    tvCaption.setText(cities.get(position));

    if (posClicked != -1) {
        if (posClicked == position)
            tvCaption.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    } else
        tvCaption.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

    LinearLayout llCity = view.findViewById(R.id.llCity);
    llCity.setTag(position);
    llCity.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    posClicked = (int)view.getTag();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**EDIT LAST: THERE IS WORKING CODE!**

After all editing I got this code:

Activity:

```
ListView listLibrary;
CustomArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_info);

    listLibrary = findViewById(R.id.listSongs);
    listLibrary.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    fillList();
}

private void fillList() {
    String[] arrList = {"New York", "San Francisco", "Los Angeles", "Dallas", "Houston", "Tucson", "Phoenix", "Denver", "Las Vegas", "Kansas City", "Chicago", "Detroit", "Atlanta", "Miami", "Philadelphia", "Baltimore", "Washington", "Boston", "Pittsburg", "Columbus", "Cincinnati", "Indianapolis", "St. Louis", "Seattle", "Portland", "San Jose", "San Diego", "San Antonio"};
    ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : arrList)
        cities.add(s);

    if (listLibrary != null) {
        adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_custom_item, cities);
        listLibrary.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    adapter.setCurClickedPos(i);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

And CustomAdapter:

```
ArrayList<String> cities;
Context context;
int resource;
int curClickedPos;

public CustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    cities = (ArrayList) objects;

    curClickedPos = -1;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null);
    }

    TextView tvCaption = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCaption);
    tvCaption.setText(cities.get(position));

    if (curClickedPos != -1) {
        if (curClickedPos == position)
            tvCaption.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        else
            tvCaption.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    } else
        tvCaption.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

    LinearLayout llCity = view.findViewById(R.id.llCity);
    llCity.setTag(position);

    return view;
}

public void setCurClickedPos(int curClickedPos) {
    this.curClickedPos = curClickedPos;
}
```

Comment: Did you try with custom adapter? Try with Base Adapter, then you can more to do with that

Comment: Instead of using the standard arrayadapter<string>, create your own adapter with an "onclickListener" on the textview

Comment: I had done customAdapter before I did this simple. But that one also didn't work, that is why I did simple one to ask you to help me

Comment: It is due to ListView recycle your view, that lead to duplicate bold item. You need to use custom adapter to handle it. If you update your adapter code, I can help you.

Comment: Truong Giang Dam, I've added the code of customAdapter. Now I have the same result. Or if to add unbold condition to getView i get normal type everywhere, so I lose bold line at all.

Comment: @mit  Is bold a requirement? If you add to your ListView for example:  "android:choiceMode="singleChoice" and android:listSelector="#666666". The Android framework will highlight the currently selected item without any custom code.

Comment: @Elletlar, thank for your advice but bold is main requirement, I can change color of background if I want, but textviews must be bold after had been clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your getView() function, you are reusing your views. So while creating views you will have to check if the item was clicked or not. When you check if posClicked is not equal to -1, in that if block you need to add an else statement as well like below:

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    // your logic here
    if (posClicked != -1) {
        if (posClicked == position)
            tvCaption.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        else
            tvCaption.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    } else
        tvCaption.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, you are exactly right. I've forgotten to add making Normal to else statement. But could you answer this question: is it possible to avoid set/get tags to views to get their position number. I consider it is little bit stupid to use it in this case.

Comment: you are using a listview or a recyclerview?

Comment: if you are using listview, add onItemClickListener on your listview. its implementation gives you position by default. @mit

Comment: you mean then to add it to public variable and then inside adapter compare it with current, don't you?

Comment: check below thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448585/how-to-get-position-of-item-clicked-on-listview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Could you do me a favor? I have edited my code in the first post and published everything that works fine. Is that good pattern for real coding?

Comment: It is okay. However if you want to move click logic to adapter, then create a function in your adapter which takes position as an input parameter. Then from your activity where you receive the list item click event, call that method in your adapter passing the position

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right you want have a bold text inside a touched/clicked itemview.

Assuming that **posPrev** represent the index of the touched item,

- first you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (after on click event)
- then add under getView method of your custom adapter this piece of code:

  ```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {

      yourTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

      if(posPrev == position){
          yourTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: I tried to do it like you had advised but no result